# What is mysteriously slicing the inside of my tubes?

Tags: innertube, puncture

For about the last year, I've had a problem keeping my bike on the road. Originally, my rear tube went flat when the tire was punctured by an office staple (don't ask me how a regular office staple could have been positioned properly on the road and puncture all the way through the tire while I was riding, I can't figure that out either). Since then, every time I replace the tube, it lasts for maybe two weeks and then goes flat again. Each time, the tube gets this mysterious slice along the inner side. Here is a picture of one of these slices. It's very faint; only deep enough to puncture fully through the tube in a few places.
[image]
This is a picture of the inner side of the tube. The slice is almost halfway down from the seam and runs across the length of the tube shown here. My patch is covering the largest hole, but doesn't solve the problem.

The first time I saw this, I figured it was something to do with the rim. However, this slice (which is usually about 20cm long) appears in different locations relative to the valve on every new tube. So if it is something to do with the rim, it isn't anything that would be in a fixed location on the rim.

I also thought it could be due to installation error, so I made sure a few times I had professionals at the shop do the installing. Same thing; about two weeks later it would be flat with a slice like this through it.

Obviously, this has nothing to do with the tire itself, since no part of the tire is in contact with this part of the tube. Given the time it takes to form, it looks like something is gradually cutting into the tube and, after about two weeks, finally manages to wear through it. I've washed the rim thoroughly and run my fingers along it to check for slivers. Nothing. I thought maybe it was the rim strip, the edge of which contacts the tube. That's still my number 1 guess, but if that's it, why is this slice only along a ~20cm section of the tube (I've checked the rest, no slice) and always in a different place along the rim? Why wouldn't it either be in the same place or along the entire tube if it were the strip?

Anyway, this mystery has me stumped and has cost me a fortune in tubes and bus fare (what with a bike no longer being my commute option). To try to mitigate it, I've tried using self-sealing tubes, which obviously didn't work perfectly (lasted an extra few days though) because they are more suited for punctures on the outer side of the tube. My next thought is trying puncture-proof tubes. If I can't figure out how to stop these slices, I figure puncture-proof tubes would be thick enough to give me a few extra weeks per tube.

For the record, the bike is a Trek 3700 with 26X2 wheels and I usually pump the rear wheel up to about 45-50 psi.

TL;DR: What's causing these slices in my tubes? How can I prevent it?

Comment: I've gotten a flat via a staple. And FWIW - if the *professionals* can't fix this for you they are professionals in name only. Based on this picture it looks like you have abrasions under the patch and then on top of the patch. Doesn't this support the conclusion that this is happening in the EXACT same place?

Comment: You have a bit of wire from the tire bead which projects in toward the tube.  You probably damaged the tire using a screwdriver to change it at one point.

Comment: A picture of the rim, with the channel that the tube rides in, would be helpful. If you are using rim *tape,* it is possible, over time, for the adhesive to deteriorate. The tape can move around as you install the tire and/or use the wheel, exposing the spoke holes. I had this problem and went through four or five tubes before I figured it out; the poor quality tape I was using wasn't sticking. Switching to a rim strip made all the difference.

Comment: @jqning it happens at different places with each new tube. But it doesn't move around once the new tube is put in

Comment: @DanielRHicks I checked the tires previously and found nothing. I'll check again along the tire bead, just in case.

Comment: @Jimself Well the rim doesn't know that the patched tube wasn't a new tube. Fact is that between tube changes the wear spot occurred in the same place. The area where that patch is must point to precisely where the problem on the rim is. It can only be one place if you pay attention when you take the tube off.

Comment: Are you installing the tyre in the same place every time (e.g. label by valve)? Though I don't see how that would explain "different places with each new tube. But it doesn't move around once the new tube is put in".

Comment: Unless you take the tyre off when fitting a new tube and put it on in a random position, but patch without taking the tyre all the way off, so it stays in the same position once you've changed the tube. In which case Daniel is almost certainly right. If you still can't find anything, swap the front and back tyres. If the problem moves wheel with the tyre, change the tyre even if you still can't find a loose wire.

Comment: Did you always buy the same manufacturer tubes? Maybe they are bad quality?

Comment: @armb the holes occur on the inside of the tube. The rim side not the tire side.

Comment: @Alexander different brands

Comment: @jqning The position of the valve doesn't changes on the rim, but the hole is at different places relative to the valve, thus must be at different places along the rim

Comment: @Jimself OP says it is in different places along the rim. However, in the photo it's clear that 1) the tube was worn through 2) the tube was patched over the worn spot, and then 3) the patched area was worn some more. Therefore, at least between this one instance of removing and replacing the tube and tire, the problem did not move.

Comment: @jqning I know what I observed. The slice is in different places on each new tube. I am OP

Comment: @Jimself I understand that you've seen it move. I'm just saying that it doesn't necessarily move.

Comment: @jqning One tube has the slice near the valve. Another tube has the slice on the opposite side from the valve. Every tube has it in a different position relative to the valve. Since the valve hole (and thus, the valve) doesn't move on the rim, this indicates that the slices are occurring in different locations along the rim for each new tube. BTW, the patch was not worn, I just suck at patching tubes. I never put the tube back on after the patch because it couldn't cover all the holes

Comment: I've had several rear tire flats from staples.  My theory is that I'm hitting it with both wheels.  The front wheel rolls over it and bounces it up a bit so that when the back wheel hits it, it can puncture the tire.

Comment: What sort of rims do you have? Are the slices really 20cm / 8 inches long? I have been having a similar issue with randomly placed 2cm slices on the rim side of the tube. My rims have a valley 5 mm or so deep. The rim tape (Velox 12mm) completely fills the bottom of the valley. My current theory is that the valley is causing stress on the tube. As the tube is filled the tube is sticking on the top edge of the valley and expanding to fill the valley. The edges of the valley are roughly right angles creating a lot more stretch both at the start of the valley and even more when it hits the corner

Comment: Punctures have causes, and in your case, new rim tape is probably the answer.  You might get away with adding some layers of light rope/cord like sash cord in the valley under the rim tape.

Comment: No his gashes were probably 2 mm long.  Even 20mm would be too long for that patch.

Comment: The slices were along the length of the tube. I solved the problem though. It was the rim tape, the adhesive degraded (allowing the tape to reposition itself every time the tube was changed) and the tape wore to a sharp edge, which would slice through the tube only when riding the bike.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree with your diagnosis: it must be related to the rim tape.

Take it off and inspect it and the rim below. If you don't find anything obvious, buy new, good quality rim tapes, check there are no sharp edges, and reinstall.

Comment: any suggestions for *if* this persists after changing the rim tape?

Comment: Yep. A few layers of electrical tape, covering the edges of the rim tape. You could try that now, since it's cheap and easy. It's an annoying kind of problem. Just go one step further with each "solution".

Comment: The last tube went flat while biking to the store to pick up new tubes. If that happens again my next "solution" will probably involve fire. I'll try this out first though

Comment: I would go with a rim *strip* instead of rim tape, and be sure it is the correct width. Too, I would be very uncomfortable introducing electric tape into that environment. I have no idea how the vinyl in the tape, plus the adhesive, would react with the butyl rubber of the tube/rubber of the tire.

Comment: @Zippy I've used electrical tape and duct tape successfully. When saying *rim tape* I'm thinking of the tough plastic ones.

Comment: Rim tape: http://www.amazon.com/Velox-Fond-Jante-tape-17mm/dp/B001AYCJ6S

Comment: Rim strip: http://www.amazon.com/Ritchey-Rim-Strips-26x20mm-Blue/dp/B000QSWAUO

Comment: I understand the terms are sometimes interchanged, but truly tape has an adhesive side, whereas the rim *strip* has no adhesive.

Comment: @Jimself, again I would encourage, *don't* use electrical tape or duct tape inside your tire. A good quality rim strip, properly installed, should solve your problem. Be sure to buy the right size. https://youtu.be/X8NfF3vTY08

Comment: @ZippyThePinhead okay, I'm using a rim strip then. A fabric strip. Came with the wheel

Comment: @jimself Not to be picky, but is this really the answer here since it has been 20 hours since posting, and it normally takes a few days before it goes flat?  Or did you find that your existing rim strip was damaged?

Comment: @Jimself, look at the way the tape or strip or whatever is lying in the channel of the wheel. Can it move in any way? If so, can the spoke holes be exposed? If so, this may be the root of the problem. Your picture looks to have a patch obscuring the cut; can you show a picture of the cut?

Comment: @ZippyThePinhead I'd love to provide a better picture, but my bike is in a different town right now. I'll get a picture up here in a couple days when I'm reunited with it

Comment: I've always considered rim tape to be superior to rim strips, but I've never seen a rim strip of the style in Zippy's link -- they're always the thin rubber things.  However, I'm skeptical of either being the problem, unless it's allowing spoke ends to poke through (and the symptoms don't suggest that).  It's almost certainly something associated with the tire itself.

Comment: @DanielRHicks The tire doesn't contact the tube where the lice is happening. I'll upload a picture of the rim strip later today. The slice occurs near where I think the tube contacts the edge of the strip. I'm no doctor, but that *could* be what's causing this

Answer (score 1):

Your solutions have all pretty much been said, it seems to be a problem with the rim. However, instead of just checking the rim tape, check the whole inner rim to make sure there are no metal shards or other pokey things embedded in the bottom or inner walls. This happens a lot with v-brakes especially, so be aware.

Speaking of brakes, I also wanted to mention that you might have a look at your own. Usually an overlooked source of the problem, brake condition/position can play a crucial role in your tyres lifespan.

Comment: 1) I have disc brakes, new pads too. And 2) I checked the rim for shards, thank you for the suggestion. There were none.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally get the rim tape of and give it a good inspection and clean. If you suspect anything from that, replace it.

I would also check spoke tension in case your wheel is knackered and spokes are pushing through. This shouldn't be the case and if it is, you need a new wheel. Having said that, you may have a bit of spoke protruding through the nut in to the body of the rim, you might be able to swap it out for a new spoke.

Check the tyre too. If, as you say the offset from the valve changes each time, think what else would be aligned differently after a puncture repair? Inspect the bead, carefully run your finger or better still some sort of cloth that easily catches. Something that acts like silk does but don't use silk unless you're minted.

Replace the tyre, they're relatively cheap and if you're spending all your cash on tubes then you may as well try and eliminate one element sooner rather than later.

More of an aside, your patching could be better. You want the glue to cover a decent area that extends beyond the patch size and let it dry before applying the patch. By doing that you'll get an instant grab on the patch (so get it lined up well) and press it down thoroughly working from the centre out. The feathered edge should be less likely to peel up then but you'll still need to coax it off the backing a bit. Use the chalk to dust the whole area afterwards.